# How do I create a pdf optimised to display faster on an iPad using Goodreader?

Tags: pdf, ipad, microsoft-onenote-2010

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.  I have a pdf that takes a while to display on my iPad.  The software on my iPad is Goodreader, latest version (3.1.2). I created the pdf in OneNote 2010 by using the regular save-as-pdf feature. How do I optimize the pdf to display faster?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you save the PDF you save it for screen only or for 72 DPI. The higher (300 or 600 dpi) resolution for printing will balloon the file size and if you're not printing it, there's no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to simplify/strip down a PDF.

[pdf2pdf](https://github.com/marten/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/pdf2pdf)

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dCompatibilityLevel="$pdfver" -sOutputFile="$outfile" -f "$inFile"
```

Comment: This looks good. Is there Windows friendly way to do this?

Comment: Not a clue. But I'm sure GS can be invoked the same way as the script does.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use the script as a starting point.  GSView didn't solve my problem but it might work for somebody else and I learned something new about gsview.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: The script has disappeared from the linked location, can you upload a copy here?